# Find the radius of circle with a regular octagon and a dodecagon inscribed in it

Tags: geometry, circles

> A regular octagon and a regular dodecagon ($12$ sides) are both inscribed in a circle, with their vertices lining up whenever possible. If the largest distance between two points on the circumference is $16 \pi$, what is the radius of the circle?

The answer key says $96$ is the radius of the circle. That would mean the radius is bigger than the minor arc. Is that right?

There are 15 degree differences between the different sequence of points. $\dfrac{2\pi\cdot r\cdot15}{360}=16\pi$. unless you mean the large distance is the distance from $0$ to $360$ degrees, which implies radius is $8$.

Comment: Could you explain what "largest distance between two points on the circumference" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the largest distance between two points on the circumference

As I read this, it doesn't say the points are consecutive vertices of either polygon. (It technically doesn't say the points are *any* vertices of the polygons, either, but I suppose from the way the problem is worded that the "points" are the same ones we were trying to line up in the previous sentence.)

It also doesn't say how the distance is measured. Yes, it says "on the circumference," but that makes the most sense as a description of the location of the points.
If I meant to say that the measurement of distance should be the length of a circular arc lying on the circumference, I would use such explicit wording to say so, or I would say *along* the circumference.

By default, we measure distances between points as straight-line distance.

So we are looking at the farthest-apart vertices, which for the combined octagon-dodecagon will be two vertices at opposite ends of a diameter.
The distance between these points is the length of the diameter, $16\pi.$
The radius is half the diameter, $8\pi.$

Obviously this is an entirely different interpretation than was desired, but I blame poor wording of the question.

---

According to what I guess the author of the problem *wanted* to ask
(as opposed to what they actually *did* ask),
$16\pi$ is supposed to be the larger of the two possible arc lengths between consecutive vertices of either polygon along the circle.
The arc lengths are $2\pi r/12$ between consecutive vertices of the dodecagon when no vertex of the octagon lies between these vertices of the dodecagon
(in this case, one of the two dodecagon vertices coincides with a vertex of the octagon),
and $2\pi r/24$ between a vertex of the dodecagon and the vertex of the octagon when a vertex of the octagon lies between two consecutive vertices of the dodecagon.
The larger distance is $2\pi r/12,$ hence
\begin{align}
 2\pi r/12 &= 16\pi \\
 r/12 &= 8 && \text{Divide both sides by $2\pi.$} \\
 r &= 96  &&\text{Multiply both sides by $12.$} \\
\end{align}

---

Note that $2\pi/12 = \pi/6$ radians comes out to $30^\circ.$
Your $15^\circ$ angle is the smaller central angle between consecutive vertices along the circle.
And yes, either of these angles is less than one radian, hence the radius will be bigger than the arc length.

Comment: Why is the answer throw out the information about the octagon? How do you know that "no vertex of the octagon lies between the dodecagon's vertices" pictorally?

Comment: We do have vertices of the octagon that lie between vertices of the dodecagon. Where that happens you get a $15^\circ$ arc. I added some words to the answer to clarify this. Since the question asked for *largest* distance between two consecutive points, however, we use the $30^\circ$ arc that we find elsewhere on the circle. It is strange that the question specified an octagon that turns out to have no effect on the result, but that is what the question is.

Comment: Are you using the fact that the every multiple of 30 is also a multiple of 15?

Comment: I don't think that's particularly relevant. What is important is that if you line up the two polygons so that they each have a vertex at the same point on the circle, and call this the point at $0^\circ$, then you have vertices of the octagon at $45^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $180^\circ$, $225^\circ$, $270^\circ$, and $315^\circ$, while you have vertices of the dodecagon at $30^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$, etc. Draw these points on a circle. All the gaps are either $30^\circ$ (e.g. $0^\circ$ to $30^\circ$) or $15^\circ$ (e.g. $30^\circ$ to $45^\circ$).

Comment: Alternatively, by the pigeonhole principle we know that no matter how the polygons are inscribed, there will be at least one pair of vertices of the dodecagon with no octagon vertex between them, since the dodecagon has more sides than the octagon has vertices. So there will be at least one $30^\circ$ arc. But because the dodecagon cuts the circle into $30^\circ$ arcs, all the octagon can do is cut those arcs into smaller arcs; it cannot make them into larger arcs. So the largest arc is $30^\circ$.

Comment: If we had a pentagon instead of an octagon only one vertex could be lined up with a vertex of the dodecagon; the smallest arc would be $12^\circ$, and the largest would still be $30^\circ$ even though $30$ is not a multiple of $12.$

Answer (score 0):

I believe the largest distance means the largest distance between two consecutive points is $16\pi$. Drawing a picture one can easily see that this is just the distance between two consecutive vertices of the dodecahedron. Therefore, we just multiply by $12$ to get the circumference and divide by $2\pi$ to get the radius, $96$.